# Integration formula for $C^1$ functions

Tags: integration, derivatives, monotone-functions

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ and $f(x)=0$ in $[0,\varepsilon]$ and $[1-\varepsilon,1]$ for some given $\varepsilon<1$. Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ be monotonically increasing. I'm trying to understand the following integration formula: Let $E_t:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: u(x)\geq t\}$ and $\chi_t$ is the indicator function over $E_t$. How can I see that
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_0^1 f(u(x))dx = \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^{1-\varepsilon} f'(t) \chi_{t}dt dx
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Idea is the following:

Rewrite $f(u(x))$ as
\begin{align}
f(u(x) ) = \int_0^{u(x)} f^\prime(t)dt
\end{align}
which we can do since $f \in C^1$ and $f(0)=0$.

Since $f=0$ on $[0,\varepsilon]$ the same holds for $f^\prime$, i.e. $f^\prime=0$ on $[0,\varepsilon]$. This means

\begin{align}
\int_0^{u(x)} f^\prime(t)dt = \int_\varepsilon^{u(x)} f^\prime(t)dt
\end{align}

We can kind of do the same for the upper bound: If $u(x) \geq 1-\varepsilon$ holds we can change the upper bound of the integral to $1-\varepsilon$ and the value of the integral will not change. But if $u(x) < 1-\varepsilon$, the value would change. But we can counter this by multiplying with the indicator function over the set $\{t \leq u(x)\}$ inside the integral.

Overall it should hold
\begin{align}
f(u(x) ) = \int_0^{u(x)} f^\prime(t)dt = \int_\varepsilon^{1-\varepsilon} f^\prime(t) \mathcal{X}_tdt
\end{align}.